# Instantiation/Template function specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-function

I'm reading a book on C++ and for some reason I can't seem to understand Template Specialization (Implicit Template Instantiation, Explicit Template Instantiation, and Explicit Specialization) of functions.

To be clear, I don't understand the need for explicit template instantiation or explicit specialization when one could just declare/define a non-template function, which would override both a generic template function and a specialization.

Where, when, and why would you use explicit template instantiation and/or explicit specialization of functions?

Comment: Are you confused between template functions and template classes?  Specialization is generally for classes, not for functions, and the reason you gave for lack of need for specialization (though not really correct in itself) was for functions.  The need for specialization should be more obvious for a class.

Comment: The common reason for explicit instantiation is to allow significant definition parts to be in cpp files, rather than hpp files.  Non templated code typically has declaration in hpp and definition in cpp and there are good reasons for that split.  Templated code typically cannot be split that way.  But explicit instantiation often lets you split it that way when you otherwise couldn't.

Comment: [This](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) may be useful.

Comment: @JSF, I'm still on template functions. I haven't reached template classes yet. Your comment on explicit instantiation helps, but wouldn't explicitly instantiating a function "overlook" (for lack of a better word) the whole point of generic programming by explicitly stating which types could be used for the function? Although, I can see how that would save time as you wouldn't have to define a seperate function for each type. Quentin, Awesome, thank you for the read! Hopefully, it clears things up.

Comment: @Jonathan In my OPINION, that kind of use of explicit instantiation does run counter to the philosophy of object oriented programming and defeat what you are thinking of as the "point" of generic programming. And that is a GOOD thing.  Excess attempts at generality is one of major flaws in professional C++ programming.  There certainly exist situations that call for philosophically correct generic programming.  But there are also situations best treated as a small set of specific possibilities.

Comment: Example, where I work an ENORMOUS amount of templates were written that are used for `double` or `std::complex<double>`.  That code was written all in hpp files and all with excess generality that pretends it could make sense for value types that the code knows far less about.  This design has been a maintenance nightmare.  It is a great advantage of C++ that you can write such code once, rather than twice, yet have the full run time efficiency you might get if you had written it twice.  But that should have been done without the maintenance costs from attempts at excess generality.

Comment: @JSF, You've made a great point. Certain situations call for certain design patterns and use of tools, which is a point that I need to keep in mind when reading about these types of things. Could you elaborate on excess generality? For instance, did the person use operators that may or may not work with objects of another type? If so, could this not be solved by operator overloading? Or might that be a bad idea because of the possible need to tailer the operator to the function? By the way, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This really isn't the right forum to dig into that "excess generality" issue.  There are some very serious problems there, but no concise way to describe them.  So I'll just mention that the obvious hpp/cpp issue is also part of that maintenance problem.  If one planned from the start that only `double` and `std::complex<double>` were supported, one tiny incantation per cpp file would be enough to get all of it instantiated, despite having all the definitions in cpp files and only declarations in hpp.  But as coded, it is all in hpp files and that is neither easy to live with nor correct.

Answer (score 2):

One area where this is useful is when you want to overload functions just by different return type. This is not supported for normal functions as there is no way for the compiler to resolve ambiguity of which one variant to call. But with template functions you can achieve this

```
template<typename T> 
T func() 
{
    ...
}

template<>
std::string func()
{
    ...
}

template<>
bool func()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;}; template<class T> T func() { return func(tag<T>{}); }`, ie tag dispatching to `std::string func(tag<std::string>)` instead of specializing `template<> std::string func<std::string>()`, would let you avoid having to do template specialization here.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, in modern C++, explicit function template specialization is rarely done.

First, because it works quite differently than template class specialization in a number of ways, and programmers who are used to template class specialization (which is far more common) are going to have their intuition turned upside down.

Second, because function overloading, template pattern matching, and explicit template specialization all have impact on what code is called, and all 3 tend to happen at the same point.  Function overloading and template pattern matching are complex enough to start with: explicit template specialization adds another layer of complexity that makes your code harder to understand.  It has to justify that cost.

Third, because we have learned more powerful techniques since the language was invented.  We can tag dispatch, dispatch to traits classes, or use SFINAE to pick between template overloads.  Between them they can do almost everything explicit specialization can do, and often more.

I can show you an example of where I have used it in my code.  I have a method, `GetField`, that can either get a `Cow`, `Duck` or `Otter`.  I could expose `GetCow`, `GetDuck` and `GetOtter`, but often the code that works with these 3 is symmetrical.  By making it `GetField<Cow>`, I can have the same code be templated on the choice of animal.

I then specialized the `GetField` for only those 3 types.  Now asking for any other type generates a linker error, and I get the uniform syntax I like.  The implementation of `GetField` is different for the 3 types, but the use is uniform.

If I was to write it today, I would make `GetField` like this instead:

```
// a template for passing types as tags:
template<class T> struct tag{using type=T;};

// Type-specific getters:
Cow& GetField( tag<Cow> ) { /* impl */ }
Duck& GetField( tag<Duck> ) { /* impl */ }
Otter& GetField( tag<Otter> ) { /* impl */ }

// Template getter for "any" type:
template<class T>
auto GetField()->
decltype( GetField( tag<T>{} ) )
{
  return GetField( tag<T>{} );
}
```

and I'd get better error messages (no overload instead of linker errors), and my implementations of `GetField` would be in bog-standard functions instead of in template specializations.  In this case, the template function is just a bit of interface gloss.

Between the power of traits types, tag dispatching, and overloading, I haven't run into a case where template function explicit specialization was the best solution in years, and when I revisit problems that used it in the past I usually reconsider and use other techniques.

Comment: That's very interesting. I've not run in to trait types, tag dispatching, template pattern matching, or SFINAE yet. The book I'm reading focuses on C++98 and throws in a little C++11. Some of the code you've provided I don't understand but I should be able to figure it out after I finish. *Hopefully*.

Comment: Tag dispatching is easy.  You create a (usually trivial) type that determines which overload you want to call, then you call it.  `tag<T>` is just a type that is empty, but knows what `T` is: this lets us pass the template type parameter as a function parameter instead.  The strange part is the `auto` and `-> decltype()` in the `GetField` function: that is just a way to have the return type be deduced (by a call to the tag-dispatched `GetField`), and as a side effect make an invalid `T` generate an easier to understand error (cannot find an overload, instead of a linker error).